# I'm not able create virtual environment using virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

```
C:\Users\NAVEEN\Desktop\Demo>virtualenv venv

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\naveen\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\naveen\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\NAVEEN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\naveen\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .run import cli_run
  File "c:\users\naveen\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\run\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .plugin.activators import ActivationSelector
  File "c:\users\naveen\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\run\plugin\activators.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import ComponentBuilder
  File "c:\users\naveen\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\run\plugin\base.py", line 7, in <module>
    from importlib.metadata import entry_points
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.metadata'
```

Comment: please try below commands python3 -m venv myvenv or python -m venv myvenv

for more : https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation/

Comment: Wecome to Stack Overflow ! Please review the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions. You will greatly improve your chances of getting good answers if your question has context and shows some efforts.

Comment: how did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.6+, the pyvenv module is deprecated.Your python interpreter version is **3.8.**

*Use the following one-liner instead:*

```
python3 -m venv <myenvname>
```

> Python already ships with its builtin "virtualenv" called venv since
>   version 3.3. You no longer need to install or download the virtualenv
>   scripts for Python 3.3+.

[Refer the doc for more](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and [Another stackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39713544/12210002)

Answer (score 1):

You want to write it like this:

```
python -m venv {virtualenv}
```

replace '{virtualenv}' with the name you want your virtual environment to have.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt install virtualenv
Using comand 
pip install  virtualenv
Or
pip3 install virtualenv(for linux)
Then you can create a venv
You can check version ov virtualenv using comand
virtualenv --version